# How to make a rectangular clockwise progress in iOS?

Tags: ios, progress-bar, rectangles

I'm struggling to create a rectangular clockwise progress in iOS. See the attached images to understand better what I mean:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If anyone has some useful ideas, please share them. Thank you.

Comment: Off the top of my head may be experiment with BezierPath with rect ?

Comment: It's easily doable with `CALayer`s or four narrow `UIView`s on the four sides of the rectangle; just animate their height accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a reactangular loader. You can have a look at the code here
https://github.com/NavneetSinghGill/ReactangularLoader.git

There's a method named `getPointsForValue` which does the main work.